# Web Deployment runs with error, but does nothing

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm running a CI pipeline on Azure DevOps. Part of the release pipeline is deploying a website to our web server (running IIS).

We changed hardware recently and did a fresh install of Windows. Of course I also installed the WebDeploy handlers and everything. But since then, the deployment runs without error, but it doesn't actually update any files. If I publish the website from VS2019, everything is fine.

How would I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Hi friend, how does your pipeline definitions look like? Maybe you can check the detailed log (set System.Debug=true) of the deploy task and make sure the website is actually be deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include the new server into the deployment group. Only noticed it when we finally turned off the old server and got the error message that the target was offline.